How to get accurate code coverage report using gcovr for MSYS2 MINGW64 Clang project?
I try to use gcovr tool to obtain code coverage of a C++ project built on Windows using MSYS2 MINGW64's Clang toolchain.
I've decided to use such setup to mimic how the project is built on the CI system.
The project consists of a test executable E (it uses GoogleTest framework) and two static libraries, L1 and L2, having the following dependencies: L1 -> L2; L1, L2 -> E.
It is build using CMake system.
When building for code coverage, at the very beginning of the whole process I append to all targets the following compiler flags (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS): -g --coverage -fPIC -O0 -fno-elide-constructors
Then, I generate code coverage report using the following command:
-- C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcovr.exe --html index.html --html-details -r <PROJECT_ROOT> --object-directory=<BUILD_DIR> --gcov-executable=llvm-cov gcov --merge-mode-functions=merge-use-line-min --exclude-unreachable-branches --exclude-function-lines --exclude-lines-by-pattern '^\s*\}?\s*$'
The first problem I've encountered is that for at least one source file some functions were found on multiple lines in the same file - what makes no sense to me, as e.g. gcovr reported one of such functions to start in L183 and L185, whereas it actually starts in L185 and L183 contains the closing brace of totally different function. I have no clue why I got this error, but managed to bypass it by using --merge-mode-functions=merge-use-line-min flag.
However, the resulting report is garbage. In particular, numerous empty lines as well as lines containing only comments/closing braces are marked as "not hit" what makes the output rather not useful.
Note that I've used --exclude-lines-by-pattern '^\s*\}?\s*$' flag, but for some reason it did not filter out the mentioned problematic lines.
Here is an excerpt from the generated report:

What should I do to make the results more accurate? Use different compiler/linker flags? A different coverage tool?
A different toolchain is not so feasible solution, as then I would have to constantly rebuild the whole project to switch between e.g. Clang <-> GCC.
I've tried to add -Xclang -fprofile-instrument=clang compiler flags to all build targets, but then the build process was stuck at linking my test executable E (or the process was slowed down, that I assumed it became staled; instead of completing let's say in 10-20 seconds, it did not finished even after a few minutes). 
[EDIT: It finished after some 15-20 minutes, with a long list of "undefined reference" errors occuring for GoogleTest library (libgtest.a) and related to elements of C++ standard library, e.g.:
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ld: lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.obj):C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/stl_tree.h:1964: more undefined references to '__profc__ZNKSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES5_St9_IdentityIS5_ESt4lessIS5_ESaIS5_EE14_M_lower_boundEPKSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS5_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseRKS5_' follow 
]

The garbage report suggests that gcovr is getting confused about its paths … it happens. Either gcovr is rendering the coverage info over the wrong source code in the HTML report, or is merging coverage data for different files. Headers/includes can be particularly difficult. In most cases, gcovr will be able to use better heuristics if you remove --object-directory. Instead of gcovr -r SRC --object-directory BUILD, consider gcovr -r SRC BUILD or  cd BUILD && gcovr -r ../SRC. Consider using a --txt report to see if the file paths look correct.

@amon: Thanks for the hint. However, when I've tried to run: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcovr.exe --txt test_coverage/report.txt --gcov-executable='llvm-cov gcov' .
I started to receive the following error: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Development/Spirallo/WinCanSpiralloComponent/src/formatter.h##c48e9bf35b0416fc6868130a8c8f2560.gcov'
Since I have no time to experiment too much, I've decided to switch to GCC compilation for code coverage - and now gcovr yields the expected results.
